# Redirect Logged In User to Associated Company Show Page

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-4

I have a UserSessionsController:

```
  def create
    @company = Company.find(params[:user_id])

    if login(params[:email], params[:password])
      redirect_back_or_to(users_path, message: "Logged in successfully.")
    else
      flash.now.alert = "Login Failed."
      render action: :new
    end
  end
```

I want to redirect the logged in user to the associate company's show page. Any ideas on what should replace `users_path`?

I'm just brainstorming with the `@company` bit.

Answer (score 1):

From `redirect_back_or_to` method name, I'll assume you're using Sorcery gem. Please provide such info in your questions if you want to get an accurate answer.

A quick look at [methods source code](https://github.com/NoamB/sorcery/blob/a5559324d88c8356936d4d8106070d765a96e6e2/lib/sorcery/controller.rb#L89) shows that it's just a helper method around `redirect_to` controller method.

Therefore, you can just change your line from:

```
redirect_back_or_to(users_path, message: "Logged in successfully.")
```

To:

```
redirect_back_or_to(@company, message: "Logged in successfully.")
```

Again, assuming your `Company` resource isn't nested...